# Trigger BigQuery Project Query via endpoint

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery Query that I saved in my project under Saved Queries > Project Queries.

I know that I can schedule a query at a regular interval using the Scheduled Queries functionality, but in this case, I would like to trigger the query by calling an endpoint or something similar.

For extra context, I am using the official BigQuery node.js library. I know that I can run queries that way as well, but it means I need to copy the text of the saved query and paste it in my Node.js project and call it that way - this is not an option for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider creating a Cloud Function that is triggered by an HTTP request. Then execute the [BigQuery Tutorial (2nd gen) function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/bigquery) in the function.

Comment: create a cloud function with an http trigger (like @Rohit Kharche says) and then schedule the function to run via Cloud Scheduler.  save your project query as a view or stored procedure too btw

Comment: Neither of those suggestions will work because I still need to copy the text of the query and put it in the HTTP request in order to trigger it. The query is stored in the BigQuery console, I can't copy it onto the server.

Answer (score 0):

Create a composer environment with airflow where you can use your query to run scheduled on the raw data. You could send reports but really you can do anything with airflow DAGs.

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview

You could also create an API hosted in GCP which in turn run the airflow DAG to run the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Apps Script.

It can handle your problem statement by following the below steps.

## Step 1: Access the Google Apps Script Editor

- Open your web browser and go to the Google Apps Script Editor.

## Step 2: Create a New Google Apps Script Project

- In the Google Apps Script Editor, click the "+" button in the bottom-right corner to create a new project.

## Step 3: Add Google BigQuery Service

- In the Apps Script editor, click on the "+" icon next to "Services" in the left sidebar.
- Search for "BigQuery" in the "Add a service" dialogue.
- Click the "Add" button next to "BigQuery API."

## Step 4: Create a Function to Run a BigQuery Query

- In the script editor, create a function to run a BigQuery query:

```
function doGet() {
  runBigQuery();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Ok");
}

function runBigQuery() {
  const projectId = 'your_project_id';
  const datasetId = 'your_dataset_id';
  const query = 'SELECT * FROM your_table';

  const request = {
    query,
    useLegacySql: false
  };

  const queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  const jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Poll for job completion
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
    Utilities.sleep(1000); // Pause execution for 1 second
  }

  if (queryResults.cacheHit) {
    Logger.log('Query was served from cache.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('Query results:');
    Logger.log(queryResults);
  }
}
```

#### Replace 'your_project_id', 'your_dataset_id', and 'your_table' with your BigQuery project, dataset, and table information.

## Step 5: Create a Trigger

- To set up a trigger to run your function at a specific time or event:
- In the Apps Script editor, click the clock icon in the left sidebar to access the "Triggers" page.
- Click on the "+ Add Trigger" button.
- Configure your trigger settings, such as the function to run, event source (e.g., time-driven, calendar, etc.), and the frequency.
- Click "Save."

## Step 6: Authorization and Deployment

- Ensure you've authorized the script to access your Google account and BigQuery resources.
- Deploy the script by clicking on the floppy disk icon in the toolbar. Choose a version name, then click "Deploy."
- Once deployed you will get the link which you can use as an endpoint to run BigQuery services.